# SQLSTATE[42S22]:Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Uploade_Images' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

I am working multiple picture uploader on laravel 7, for that i have prepared 2 tables
1 for the information post about the picture
2 for the pictures uploader
And I've added foreign key constraint to picture upload table, and I use the model relation to join the 2 tables, but I'm facing this problem.

> `SQLSTATE[42S22]:Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Uploade_Images' in 'field list'`

And i have seen past question regarding to this, but non of them helps my proble. Here is my code below 
Migration tables

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('imagesOfVenues', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('Name_of_Venue')->nullable();
            $table->text('location')->nullable();
            $table->text('Number_of_sits')->nullable();
           
            });
    }

//The Photo Uploader table

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('venuesPhoto', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('imagesOfVenues_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('imagesOfVenues_id')->references('id')->on('imagesOfVenues');
            $table->string('Uploade_Images')->nullable();

        });
    }
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class venuesPhoto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'venuesPhoto';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['Uploade_Images', 'imagesOfVenues_id'];

    public function imagesOfVenues()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\imagesOfVenue', 'id', 'imagesOfVenues_id');
    }

}
//The other model

class imagesOfVenue extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'imagesOfVenues';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

     protected $guarded = [];

    public function venuesPhoto()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\venuesPhoto');
    }

}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Models\imagesOfVenue;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class imagesOfVenueController extends Controller
{
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $requestData = $request->all();
                if ($request->hasFile('Uploade_Images')) {
            $extension = $request->Uploade_Images->extension();

            $requestData['Uploade_Images'] = $request->file('Uploade_Images')
                ->store('uploads', 'public');
        }

        imagesOfVenue::create($requestData);

        return redirect('admin/images-of-venue')->with('flash_message', 'imagesOfVenue added!');
    }
}
```

View Form

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('Name_of_Venue') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    <label for="Name_of_Venue" class="control-label">{{ 'Name_of_Venue' }}</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Name_of_Venue" type="text" id="Name_of_Venue" value="{{ isset($imagesofvenue->Name_of_Venue) ? $imagesofvenue->Name_of_Venue : ''}}" >
    {!! $errors->first('Name_of_Venue', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('location') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    <label for="location" class="control-label">{{ 'Location' }}</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="location" type="textarea" id="location" >{{ isset($imagesofvenue->location) ? $imagesofvenue->location : ''}}</textarea>
    {!! $errors->first('location', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('Number_of_sits') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    <label for="Number_of_sits" class="control-label">{{ 'Number_of_sits' }}</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="Number_of_sits" type="textarea" id="Number_of_sits" >{{ isset($imagesofvenue->Number_of_sits) ? $imagesofvenue->Number_of_sits : ''}}</textarea>
    {!! $errors->first('Number_of_sits', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('Uploade_Images') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
    <label for="Uploade_Images" class="control-label">{{ 'Uploade_Images' }}</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="Uploade_Images" type="file" id="Uploade_Images" value="{{ isset($imagesofvenue->Uploade_Images) ? $imagesofvenue->Uploade_Images : ''}}" >
    {!! $errors->first('Uploade_Images', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{{ $formMode === 'edit' ? 'Update' : 'Create' }}">
</div>
```

route

```
Route::resource('admin/images-of-venue', 'Admin\\imagesOfVenueController');
```

Comment: You're trying to store the $request, which contains Uploade_Images, into imagesOfVenue which does not have that column.

Comment: Yeah, i understand that. how can i store the image into the other table?

Comment: could you please show me how it do it?

Comment: Use `venuesPhoto` instead? If you have data for both tables in `$request`, then you're going to have to build up your insert/create values yourself instead.

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work it says SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'imagesOfVenues_id' doesn't have a default value. the class has no problems so far, the problem is, how can i pass the uploade_image from venue table to imagesOfVenue controller along with imageOfVenue datas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i_ofVenue =  imagesOfVenue ::create([
'Name_of_Venue' => $request->input('Name_of_Venue'),
'location' => $request->input('location'),
'Number_of_sits' => $request->input('Number_of_sits'),

]);

 $v_photo = new venuesPhoto() ; 
$v_photo->id= 11111 ; 
$v_photo->imagesOfVenues_id =$i_ofVenue->id ;
 if ($request->hasFile('Uploade_Images')) {
            $fileNameWithExtension = $request->file('Uploade_Images')->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExtension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $fileExtension = $request->file('Uploade_Images')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fullFileName = $fileName . '-' . time() . '.' . $fileExtension;
        //  $request->file('Uploade_Images')->move(public_path('images'), $fullFileName);
        } else {
            $fullFileName = 'noimage.jpg';
        }
$v_photo->Uploade_Images=$fullFileName ;
$v_photo->save() ;
```